# Titanium Backup unable to obtain root permission

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, titanium-backup, superuser, supersu, oneplus-x

I recently updated my SuperSU to 2.79. Titanium Backup has stopped working since then. I've tried reinstalling it and clearing data and cache too.

Strangely, it is trying to obtain SuperUser permission from a script in the location:

`system/bin/.ext/.su`

when I try to execute it using Android Terminal, it throws a Syntax Error.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Super Su 2.79 is *systemless root*. This does not modify the `/system` to give root powers but modifies boot partition. I have a similar root and this sometimes doesn't go well with TiBu. The workaround for me was to go to SU settings and toggle *mount namespace separation* ( in my case it should be unchecked). Reboot and try TiBu again . Let me know if this solves

Comment: Yeah I was wondering it could be because of the systemless issue. And no toggling it didn't work.

Comment: Did you Reboot? If that also doesn't work try uninstalling and reinstalling TiBu with toggling

Comment: @beeshyams yes. I think I'll downgrade SuperSU to 2.64

Comment: Systemless root Had it's own advantage. If you care for that,  try going to earlier version of Tibu

Comment: @beeshyams I went systemless to check if I could make Pokémon Go work. Failed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51828/discussion-between-beeshyams-and-philantrovert).